# Force set printer or system default printer to chromium

Tags: linux, google-chrome, printer

Have a fleet of linux machines that have different printers available which has chromium running in --kiosk-printing for auto printing. Issue when a different printer profile is selected, sometimes the browser will not use the newly selected printer, instead the browser will use the previously selected printer. To work around this, need to disable kiosk printing mode, print and in the print dialog, pick the new default printer and re-enable auto printing. I want to force the browser to use a specified printer by updating the preferences file on schedule or pass in the name of the printer to be used to the chrome.exe through a script. The solution can't be using the GUI, must be through the terminal.

My concern is updating the preferences file directly may not work till the browser is restarted or it may create some other problem. Is there a way to **force chromium to use a specific printer profile through the terminal**?